# How do I make my SQL duplicate query make sure all columns match?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update, common-table-expression

I currently have a SQL query that seems to only take one column at a time and search for dupes.

So for example if we have two records with the FIRST = 'Charles' but both of their last names are different, it will still count that as a duplicate. I want my duplicates query to make sure all columns match perfectly to count it as a duplicate.

This is my query

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_Number() OVER(partition BY fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, birthdate Order by (select null)) AS Rn
         FROM   WORK)
UPDATE cte
SET    BAD_CODES = Isnull(BAD_CODES, '') + 'D'
WHERE  RN > 1;
```

The data in this table is mostly just address data. Typical First/Last/Middle Address/City/State/Zip and maybe two other fields.

I want to be able to SET on one of the N duplicates (if there are 4 duplicates ignore the first one and SET the others).

For example if we have

```
ZYTA    B   ZAJACZKOWSKA            100 Malberry Ln TX  73301   052 435345543345    A                   003     D
```

and

```
ZYTA    B   ZAJACZKOWSKA            100 Malberry Ln TX  73301   052 435345543345    A                   003     D
```

we would want to ignore the first occurrence of it, but SET the second one BAD_CODES column to D.

Currently the way it works is, if we have

```
ZYTA    B   ZAJACZKOWSKA            100 Malberry Ln TX  73301   052 435345543345    A                   003     D
```

and

```
ZYTA        Stevenson           100 Meow Ln 73301   052 435345543345    A                   003     D
```

That will count as a duplicate and it will code the Zyta Stevenson as a duplicate even though it is not the same as the first one.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Your query would appear to do what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I feel like it has worked in the past, but for some reason it does not seem to be working correctly this time. Any idea why?

Comment: @jarlh See updated.

Comment: @rohanharrison:Check out this link to improve question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. One thing I left out of my post was that I needed to filter these records by DS ='VOTER', but I was putting this on the last line in the WHERE RN > 1. This needed to go in the select above.

This is what I ended up using.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_Number() OVER(partition BY fips_county_code, last, suffix, first, birthdate Order by (select null)) AS Rn
         FROM   WORK
         WHERE DS = 'VOTER')
UPDATE cte
SET    BAD_CODES = Isnull(BAD_CODES, '') + 'D'
WHERE  RN > 1;
```